# How to fix "Invalid encoding' error in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, encode, iso-8859-1

I was creating a python-based shell where I used one latin-1 character: "└──>". So I tried this:

```
~python 3.8
# -*- coding:  latin-1 -*-

input_prompt = input('''
└──>  ''')
```

But it gave me error:

```
Invalid encoding 'latin-1'
Saving as 'UTF-8'
```

Why does it displays this? I tried code in python 2.7 and same error. How to solve this?

Comment: saves fine on PyScripter. What's your code editor/IDE

Comment: My editor is default:  Python IDLE

Comment: I suggest you try PyScripter or PyCharm. The files saves OK on pyscripter

Comment: I try as much as I can to avoid depending an file encoding (at least when few non ascii characters are involved. Here I would use: `input_prompt="\u2514\u2500\u2500>"`.

Comment: All characters available in Latin-1 can also be encoded in UTF-8 (which encodes *all* characters in Unicode). While I understand that you want to have control over the choice of encoding, I don't see why you would prefer Latin-1 over UTF-8. There's no real advantage as far as I can see.

Comment: First: I won't use pyscript or pycharm. Problem is that script displays error in python's idle when I am adding encoding which I showed. Without it, it displays this character but when I run it in shell or cmd, it displays as other letters .

Comment: Second: Why does it works on other script downloaded from internet and why doesn't it works on my script. Is this problem because version difference? Downloaded script was 2.7, and my script is 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry guys but I found that problem was that I must first encode this character to utf-8 which would get: 'âââ>' and then add the header. So I'm must replace those characters into 'âââ>'.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt string is not composed of characters that can be represented in latin-1, hence the error:

```
>>> s = '''└──>'''
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> for c in s:print(ud.name(c))
... 
BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND RIGHT
BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
GREATER-THAN SIGN
>>> s.encode('latin-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Either change the source file encoding to one that can support these characters (such as UTF-8) or use only characters that can be encoded as latin-1.

Comment: This character is from latin-1. It worked on other script downloaded from internet and you want to say that it isn't from latin-1? How to change this symbol to symbol that would like as this and will be encoded to latin-1 or utf-8 without any problem?

Comment: You say "the character", but in fact this is a string composed of four characters.  Perhaps there is a copy/paste problem somewhere?  Can you check whether it's a single character in the original script (and if it is, what is the value of `unicodedata.name(char)`)?

Comment: No need more answers, I found problem. Original in utf-8 it would be 'âââ>'. So I'm must replaced those into 'âââ>' and then add header.